# Redux Store not populated before Component Render

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on the authentification procedure for an app I'm developing.

Currently, the user logins in through Steam. Once the login is validated the server redirects the user to the app index, `/`, and issues them a pair of JWTs as `GET` variables. The app then stores these in a Redux store before rewriting the URL to hide the JWT tokens for security purposes.

The app then decodes the tokens to obtain info about the user, such as their username and avatar address. This *should* be rendered in the app's `SiteWrapper` component, however, this is where my problem occurs.

What seems to be happening is `SiteWrapper` component loads before the `App` component finishes saving the tokens and thus throws errors as variables are not defined. Most of the fixes that seem relevant are for API requests, however, in this case, that is not the case. I already have the data in the URL. I'm not sure if the same applies.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Any other best practice advice would be appreciated. I'm new to both React and Redux.

**Error**

[image: Error]

**Index**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

// console debug setup
window.store = store;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import "tabler-react/dist/Tabler.css";

import history from './utils/history';

import {
    storeRefreshJWTToken,
    storeAccessJWTToken,
    loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken
} from "./redux/app";

import {
  HomePage
} from './pages';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        //Get tokens from URL when app loads and then hide them from url.
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        if(urlParams.has('access_token') && urlParams.has('refresh_token')){
            this.props.storeRefreshJWTToken(urlParams.get('refresh_token'));
            this.props.storeAccessJWTToken(urlParams.get('access_token'));

            //Load user info from obtained tokens.
            this.props.loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken();
        }
        history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.StrictMode>
              <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} history={history}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                </Switch>
              </Router>
            </React.StrictMode>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    storeRefreshJWTToken,
    storeAccessJWTToken,
    loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**SiteWrapper**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
    Site,
    Nav,
    Grid,
    List,
    Button,
    RouterContextProvider,
} from "tabler-react";

class SiteWrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        this.accountDropdownProps = {
            avatarURL: this.props.user.avatar,
            name: this.props.user.display_name,
            description: "temp",
            options: [
                {icon: "user", value: "Profile"},
                {icon: "settings", value: "Settings"},
                {isDivider: true},
                {icon: "log-out", value: "Sign out"},
            ],
        };
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Site.Wrapper
                headerProps={{
                    href: "/",
                    alt: "Tabler React",
                    imageURL: "./demo/brand/tabler.svg",
                    navItems: (
                        <Nav.Item type="div" className="d-none d-md-flex">
                            <Button
                                href="https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react"
                                target="_blank"
                                outline
                                size="sm"
                                RootComponent="a"
                                color="primary"
                            >
                                Source code
                            </Button>
                        </Nav.Item>
                    ),
                    accountDropdown: this.accountDropdownProps,
                }}
                navProps={{ itemsObjects: this.props.NavBarLinks }}
                routerContextComponentType={withRouter(RouterContextProvider)}
                footerProps={{
                    copyright: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            Copyright © 2018
                            <a href="https://thomas-smyth.co.uk/"> Thomas Smyth</a>.
                            All rights reserved.
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                    nav: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Grid.Col auto={true}>
                                <List className="list-inline list-inline-dots mb-0">
                                    <List.Item className="list-inline-item">
                                        <a href="/developers">Developers</a>
                                    </List.Item>
                                    <List.Item className="list-inline-item">
                                        <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
                                    </List.Item>
                                </List>
                            </Grid.Col>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </Site.Wrapper>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        user: state.App.user
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SiteWrapper);
```

**Reducer**

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

//JWT Auth
const STORE_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN = "STORE_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN";
export const storeRefreshJWTToken = (token) => ({type: STORE_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN, refresh_token: token});

const STORE_JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "STORE_JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN";
export const storeAccessJWTToken = (token) => ({type: STORE_JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token: token});

// User
const LOAD_USER_FROM_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN = "DEC0DE_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN";
export const loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken = () => ({type: LOAD_USER_FROM_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN});

export default function reducer(state = initialState.app, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case STORE_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                jwtAuth: {
                    ...state.jwtAuth,
                    refresh_token: action.refresh_token
                }

            };
        case STORE_JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                JWTAuth: {
                    ...state.jwtAuth,
                    access_token: action.access_token
                }

            };
        case LOAD_USER_FROM_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN:
            const user = jwt_decode(state.jwtAuth.refresh_token);
            return {
                ...state,
                user: user
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware  } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

import App from './app';

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    App
});

const store = createStore(combinedReducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default store;
```

Comment: Where are you rendering `App` and `SiteWrapper`?

Comment: @Colin `App` is rendered in `index.js`, as standard. I've added it to the question. `SiteWrapper` is rendering from `HomePage`, but currently, that is simply a `return` containing the `SiteWrapper` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue. It seems this was one of those rare cases where trying to keep things simple and develop was bad.

Now, when my application loads I either show the user information or a login button.

Once the key is loaded from the URL the component rerenders to show the user information.

This does increase the number of renders, however, it is probably the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is going to run *after* first render. So on first render the `this.props.user` inside will be `null` at that point.

You could:

- move the async call to `componentWillMount()` (not recommended)
- put a guard in the `SiteWrapper`() so it can handle `null` case
- not render `Home` from the `App` until the async call has finished

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will avoid the first option if you do not recommend it. The second is not really relevant as it should not really be null. How would I go about implementing the third option?

Comment: It will be `null` though until `loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken()` finishes running, isn't it an async call?

Comment: I'm a little unsure, you'll have to excuse me I'm still rather new to advanced Javascript stuff. `loadUserFromJWTRefreshToken()` only gets the tokens from the page's current URL query string. Due to the way Steam Login works I had to redirect on the webserver from a different page where they are authenticated to the app while passing the JWTs, which are put in the query string.

Comment: Okay, regardless, you're getting `null` in your `SiteWrapper`. In your render, add something like `if (!this.props.user) { return null; }`

Answer (score 0):

in componentDidMount() you are expecting user to be set.

You can:

- Set user in initial state with some "isAuth" flag that you can easily check
- As componentWillMount() is deprecated you can use [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to check if user state is changed and do some actions.
- Use asyns functions when sawing YWT

Answer (score 0):

You could of course check for null and don't try to show the user's details in your SiteWrapper's componentDidMount()-method. But why? Do you have an alternative route to go if your user couldn't be found and is null? I guess no. So you basically have **two** options:

1. The ideal solution is to implement **async actions** and show an activity
   indicator (e.g. spinner) until the jwt-token is loaded. Afterwards
   you can extract your user information and fully render your
   component as soon as the fetch is succesfully completed.
2. If you can't use async action, for whatever reason, I would suggest
   the "*avoid-null*" approach. Put a **default user** in your initial
   state and it should be done. If you update the user prop, the
   component will rerender anyways (if connected properly).